# Java 8, Update 73 not installing

Tags: macos, java

I'm following [the procedure on Oracle's website](http://java.com/en/download/help/mac_install.xml) to install Java 8, update 73. When I get to step 5 in the procedure and click "Next," the installer window quietly shuts down without and without an error message and Java never installs. I have [tried disabling SIP](http://www.imore.com/el-capitan-system-integrity-protection-helps-keep-malware-away) to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling existing JRE per [these instructions](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml) and installing the latest Java Development Kit [from here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) did the trick.